# Hypothesis Test to Determine if Two Variables Affect Third Variable

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing

I have a systematic workflow. There are three steps: I, II, and III. In step I, a measurement is taken. In step II, another measurement is taken. In step III, a value is output.

I am interested in a hypothesis test to determine if the values measured in steps I and II significantly affects the value output in step 3.

This will be a multiple hypothesis test. In step I, a measurement is taken for 12 different items. In step II, the 12 items are divided into 4 groups of 3 items. A measurement is taken for each of the 4 groups. In step III, a value is output for each of the 12 items. This is simplified representation of the actual system.

Visual representation:

`step I` (12 individual measurements) -> `step II` (4 individual measurements) -> `step III` (12 values are output)

For this workflow, is there a statistic I can generate to test for statistical significance? Again, I want to know if the measurements taken during steps I and II significantly affects the value outputted in step III. I know the values for each step, and I have enough data points to determine statistical significance.

Comment: You could, theoretically, use an algorithm from the ReliefF family, where one of the variables would be used as target w.r.t. the other two. If the importances are similar, they matter similarly.

Comment: Why not a regression model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like a regression model would work here. Each StepIII output has a value for a StepI measurement and a StepII measurement, even if some of them share the same StepII measurement due to the grouping that occurs there.

So a regression model where the StepIII output is the dependent variable and the StepI and StepII measurements are the independent variables should test your hypothesis.  If your dependent variable is normally distributed then a standard linear model will do, otherwise you may want to look at using a generalized linear model.